Struggling to get specific information from ansible_facts output. What I can study to get a better understanding? jinja2, python, yaml?
I am trying to figure how to grab values reported by the ansible_facts. I don't know what I don't know, so I asking for help on what i need to learn in order to understand how to manipulate the data to get what i want.
Example: From ansible_facts output for "devices" I want to get the "size" information for each dm device. Its not giving me what i want.
This playbook shows what i have tried -
$ more vargetip.yml
---

  - name: make a csv file
    hosts: remote1
    serial: 1
    gather_facts: false

    tasks:


      - ansible.builtin.setup:
          gather_subset:
            - "!all"
            - devices

      #- set_fact:
          #dmlist: "{{ ansible_devices.keys() | select('regex', '^dm')}}"


      - ansible.builtin.debug:
          var: "{{ ansible_devices.keys() | select('match', '^dm') |map(attribute='size_total') }}"

#          msg: "{{ ansible_devices.keys() | select('string')|list }}" #attr('dm') }}" #| map(attribute='ids') }}"
#          msg: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('device') | map(attribute='size_total') }}"
#          msg: "{{ ansible_mounts | map(attribute='device') | map(attribute='mount') | map(attribute='size_total')  }}"

